# Can I dynamicly create adsense code?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I want to place ads on my website depending on what screen size the user uses.
The way I want to achieve it is to assign to each adsense ad min and max width. If device is big enough it will receive bigger ad. I want to do this by creating an array of objects. Each object will contain width, height, client and slot. Can I then dynamicly create an element (without all the indents and other stuff)?

It would look something like this:

`<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:'+ ad.width +'px;height:'+ ad.height +'px" data-ad-client="'+ ad.client +'" data-ad-slot="'+ ad.slot +'"></ins>`

after inserting that into the body I would call

`(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});`

so the ad would appear.

Can you tell me if you tried this and if it is good method to use? Or maybe it is not allowed? The Adsense guidelines for code modifications are not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Responsive Ad unit. It is optimised for mobile, tab and desktop screens.